# Switching output power of LED supply between 3 loads

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, led, switches, led-driver

Given an LED constant current supply (a.k.a integreated led driver, with an ac/dc conv.) with 3A output and b/w 14-24V depending on the load. The load is a series of 6 RGBW LEDs. The 3 loads I mention are the R, G, and W lines each with different forward voltage requirements at 3A. I've looked up that load switches or discrete power mosfets can be used, but that's the extent of where I've gotten. I'm thinking maybe load switches on the R, G and W lines might be the easiest solution but then again these switches have so many additional elements that i'm concerned if the output to the load is going to fluctuate the current.

Below is a visual of what I mean (not a schematic, sorry)

[image]

The drawing on the right was taken from the datasheet of a SMT RGBW LED. Just imagine 5 more of those side by side with each color connected in series. I want to switch the source between the three colors based on an input.

**Tl;dr** What is a good solution to switch the (a) supply between 3 power rails based on an input from a mcu?

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  make three different colours?

Comment: Yup that's right, three different colors, the real estate of the application calls for using RGBW led's. Sure, i'll put up a schematic.

Comment: @winny, I put up a schematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of RGB diodes are controlled by putting all colors in series and then a MOSFET in parallel with each:

[image]

This is taken from the g8208 datasheet, but it's a general circuit used for RGB LEDs. The idea is that the MOSFET on shorts out the diode but still passes current to the others in series. The constant current source then regulates the current, adjusting the voltage as mosfets turn on or off.

Note that you will need a high side gate driver for the MOSFETs that are not referenced to ground.

Comment: I'm a little confused without a visual when you mention a FET in parallel and how it shorts out the diode but passes current to the others in series. Can you please help elucidate.

Comment: @Roshan Added a picture from a commercial RGB LED.

Comment: Thanks that helps, any recommendations on a power mosfet that fits the supply criteria, there's just so many out there with a lot more to the part name than I understand.

Comment: Pick one with Rdon less than 50mOhm to avoid heating. One thing I just noticed, your supply has a lower voltage limit of 12v, which you might violate if you had only one or two LEDs on, the rest off. Make sure whatever current source you are using is ok with having however many LEDs shorted.

Comment: based off your drawing i'm instead going to have like 6 led's per color in series, so three series strings instead of the 3 individual. And will only one color to light up at a time. Is using either a NMOS or a PMOS fet alright? I'm also assuming that with this higher current rating the Vgs is gonna be high, will I potentially be able to drive this with an arduino?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're doing, but if you're ok with those voltage limitations you can use nmos.

Comment: I'm trying to switch on only white for t1 period of time, green for t2 period of time then red for t3 period of time. each of the colors have different forward voltages at 3A. hence the range of the supply that I've selected.

Comment: I don't understand how the lower voltage limit would "violate", i'm assuming i'd need a resistor if say the green string requires a stack voltage of 15 volts at 3A right?

Comment: How much voltage will be required to light up the 6 red LEDs as you propose to wire them?

Comment: 6 red - 16.2V, 6 green - 19.2V, 6 white 18.6V